# Como puedo identificar un formulario vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Quisiera saber como puedo identificar un formulario MDI-Child, y diferenciar uno de otro. Yo sé identificarlo por nombre, como se puede ver de la siguiente manera:

```
DirectCast(Application.OpenForms.Item(formulario.Name), formulario)
```

Pero que pasa en este ejemplo si el mismo formulario obviamente con un nombre repetido, puedo diferenciar un formulario de otro. Quiero saber como puedo en listar los formularios y recorrer, y poder diferenciar entre ellos, a través de una identificación o algo, Tal como un proceso abierto tiene un PID, un formulario seguramente tiene algo parecido cierto?
GRACIAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás hablando de los "Formularios" abiertos en la aplicación, puedes hacer uso de la propiedad `Application.OpenForms`. Esta es la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netframework-4.8)

Esto te devuelve una [`FormCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formcollection?view=netframework-4.8) que, a su vez, es una colección de  [`Form`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netframework-4.8) que supongo podrás iterar y sacar el identificador (por tipo).

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta tan rapida

Comment: por favor podrian ver esta consulta? que es basicamente lo mismo?https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288506/crear-una-lista-de-formulario-con-numero-y-boton-en-array-o-lista-en-vb-net