# Crear una lista de formulario con numero y un botòn en Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, formularios

Sé que es posible crear una lista de formularios con "List Of", a continuación como seria el listado para poder identificar:

```
Private ChildFormList As List(Of Form) = New List(Of Form)()
```

Quisiera saber si a esta lista de formularios, se le puede añadir en la misma lista, una variable de tipo "Integer" y un botón de toolstrip "toolstripbutton", a continuación imaginativa solución, es para explicarme.

```
Private ChildFormList As List(Of Form, Integer, ToolstripButton) = New List(Of Form, Integer, ToolstripButton)()
```

La idea es que de cada formulario se genere un numero correspondiente con un botón, Por ejemplo

> form.name("Formulario 1"), 1, toolstripbutton.name("boton1")

Es decir que el formulario "Formulario 1" le corresponde el numero 1, y el botón llamado "boton1", con esto difiero de una matriz, donde puede existir más de un formulario que de un numero, o un botón. Cada formulario debe contener un numero y un botón!. Espero que me allá expresado bien, Gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de tuplas: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurrió utilizar un diccionario, para la cual seria la siguiente forma:

```
Public ventanasabiertas As New Dictionary(Of Form, ToolStripButton)
```

Me pareció la forma correcta de utilizar, y los enumero obteniendo el índice. De esta forma logro una respuesta a mi propia respuesta, espero a que a alguien le sirva